# UNITY BUG ERROR All Camera.RenderTextures Now Render Completely Blank

Tags: unity-game-engine, screenshot

I was working improving my screenshot code that I use in a couple of apps of mine. I had copied the relevant assets to an empty project to work on them in isolation. My RenderTextures are generated through code, attached to the main Camera, rendered into and removed again from camera, then set as Texture property in RawImage component. All of a sudden, and I have no idea why, all of those RenderTexture rendered completely blank. This happened all at once and I can't seem to make it stop. I tried opening different projects that used the old code and again, EVERY RenderTexture screenshot is rendered as completely transparent with no color (or black colour, depending how you look at it). I don't know what's caused this. I don't know why it's affected other projects that I was not working on. Please Help!

```
private void Screenshot(RawImage screenshotImage) {
    RenderTexture screenshotTexture = new RenderTexture(mainCamera.pixelWidth, mainCamera.pixelHeight, 24);
    mainCamera.targetTexture = screenshotTexture;
    mainCamera.Render();
    mainCamera.targetTexture = null;
    screenshotImage.texture = screenshotTexture;
}
```

Comment: I think you have to convert `screenShotTexture` to a `Texture2D` see [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/22954/how-to-save-a-picture-take-screenshot-from-a-camer.html)

Comment: What confuses me is that this was working perfectly for weeks and today, all of a sudden, it breaks.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the Texture2D format is required to save the screenshot as a file. I don't actually need it saved as a file, I just need to draw it on the screen for cheap menu transitions. Up until today's experience, RenderTextures could be rendered in the UI directly using the RawImage Component without requiring the Texture2D conversion.

Comment: More looking and I've found that the RenderTexture has an Alpha of 0 (black) for every pixel, but the color information is correct. For some reason the RenderTexture is seemingly not recording the alpha from the Camera.

Comment: Yeah I see you are right about the Texture2D. Still odd that it changes just like that .. did you update your Unity version or anything else?

Comment: Sometimes Unity loves to mess up with a project files...

Comment: Just now everything has come good. I tried to create a new material and all of a sudden all my old materials and shaders started working perfectly again. Who knew?